# Python not able to import module

Tags: python, flask

I have quite a number of different file which I want to use to create an API. The files are :

1. app.py -- main file
2. utils.py -- utilities file
3. recorder.py
4. consts.py
5. submitter.py

All of these files have a dependency on one another. However, when I try to import them in a particular file ( for ex - importing consts in recorder.py, I am getting error saying The module consts is not found.
I am importing it using :

```
from .consts import consts
```

Can someone tell me what am I doing wrong here, and how to solve this issue.

If i import it in the main app.py, it doesn't give any error. but it does when I want to access any consts in other files.

Thank you in advance

EDIT : Here is the folder structure :

[image]

Comment: Are they all in the same folder?

Comment: @JeffUK Yes they are in the same folder

Comment: Does `import consts` work everywhere.  i.e. did you import it in the other files EXACTLY the same as in app.py  ?

Comment: Yes, I am doing the same thing, this is an issue for the other files too. I have added the folder structure too. @JeffUK

Comment: So two files in the same folder, with no differences in how you're importing it, one works and one doesn't.. are you really sure they're identical character for character?  Why `.consts` not `consts`?  Please provide a short example of both files, one where it works and one where it doesn't including the error you get (and traceback?)

Comment: So, I tried understanding circular dependency,and I tried putting all the imports in one file i.e. app.py since that's the first file being called. However, I get the same error. Let me edit and give a reproducible example.

Comment: So if I add `from .utils import utils` in app.py, it gives me error, there is no module named utils. However, if I add `from .utils import check_email` it doesn't show any error. Is there any thing that I am missing @JeffUK

Comment: Traceback - ` from .utils import utils
ImportError: cannot import name 'utils'
[2022-01-03 19:41:18 -0500] [24740] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 24740)`

Answer (score 0):

When you say they are interdependent, that may be your issue. You cannot have two files that depend directly on one another with out some hacky solutions as youll run into the problem of importing one that tries to import the importer which tries to import the importee and so on forever.

Edit: i misunderstood how imports work, the problem comes from:

> "If you import X from your main program, Python will load the code for
> X and execute it. When Python reaches the import Y statement, it loads
> the code for Y, and starts executing it instead.
>
> At this time, Python has installed module objects for both X and Y in
> sys.modules. But X doesn’t contain anything yet; the def spam
> statement hasn’t been executed."

As stated in the link i included at the bottom of this response. The link also gives some possible solutions like changing when you import the different modules.

What we really need is to see the code for the files to understand how you are importing everything

[this link](https://web.archive.org/web/20150113060057/http://effbot.org/zone/import-confusion.htm) should help you in your desire for circular dependency.

Comment: Thank you, to give more understanding, I have a utils file, which has some functions that are required in app.py and recorder.py
app.py is the main file where I am creating most of the imports for example -
from .errors import errors

from flask_restful import Resource
from .utils import utils
from .submitter import submit
from .recorder import recorder
from .consts import consts
import uuid

Now I haven't imported consts or util in recorder.py, but I am using something like - costs.MAXTHREADS. My understanding was that if it's already imported in app.py, I need not import the same

Comment: @dper check the link i added to the end of my answer, you may be able to still use circular dependancies.

Comment: To reiterate, how do I import the submittter.py in app.py